# Converting script code to composition API(setup) in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm using the following code in a page.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'FaqSection',
  props: {
    content: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      scrollArgs: {
        behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    scroll(name) {
      const collapseElement = document.querySelector(name);
      const collapseElementPosition = collapseElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      if (collapseElementPosition.bottom > windowHeight) {
        collapseElement.scrollIntoView(this.scrollArgs);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How would I update it from Vue's Options API to the Composition API **<script setup lang="ts">**

Comment: What did you try and what was the problem? SO isn't a code-writing service

Answer (score 0):

https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#composition-api

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
// Move 'components' to the top

// Move 'props' to 'defineProps' macro
// https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits
defineProps<{
  content: {}; // Record<string | number | symbol, any>
}>();

// Move 'data' 'component' 'method' to the top level
const scrollArgs = ref({ // https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'start',
  inline: 'nearest',
});
function scroll(name) {
  const collapseElement = document.querySelector(name);
  const collapseElementPosition = collapseElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  if (collapseElementPosition.bottom > windowHeight) {
    collapseElement.scrollIntoView(scrollArgs.value); // .value in <script> is required
  }
}

// Move the other options to 'defineOptions' macro
// https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineoptions
defineOptions({
  name: 'FaqSection',
});
</script>
```